# Сохранить this в callback?

Tags: javascript

Есть коллбэк `beforeLoad` FancyBox. В нем другой коллбэк `getVideo`:

```
beforeLoad: function () {
            var id = $(this.element).attr("id");
            getVideo(id, function(response){
                this.title = this.title ? this.title + 'mmm' : 'kkk';
                this.width = $(this.element).data("width");
                this.height = $(this.element).data("height");
            });
        },
```

Как сделать, чтобы объекты `this.title, this.width, this.height, this.element` были доступны в `getVideo callback`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [bind](http://learn.javascript.ru/bind), Luke!